If M is linearly compact R-module. Why does there always exist a submodule $N$ of $M$ such that $M/N$ is an Artinian module?

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a local noetherian ring and $M$ a linearly
compact $R$-module. Then $\operatorname{Cos}_R(M) = \operatorname{Cosupp}_R(M)$.

Proof. It follows from [25, 2.16] that $\operatorname{Cos}_R(M) \subseteq \operatorname{Cosupp}_R(M)$, so we need only to prove $\operatorname{Cosupp}_R(M) \subseteq \operatorname{Cos}_R(M)$. Let $p \in \operatorname{Cosupp}_R(M)$, there is a submodule $N$ of $M$ such that $M/N$ is artinian and $Ann(M/N) \subseteq p$. Thus $p \in \operatorname{Cosupp}_R(M/N)$ by [25, 2.3]. Since $M/N$ is a linearly compact $R$-module with the discrete topology, $N$ is an open submodule of $M$. Thus $N$ is open, hence $N$ is closed in $M$. That means $N$ is a linearly compact submodule of $M$. Now the short exact sequence of linearly compact modules
$0 \rightarrow N \rightarrow M \rightarrow M/N \rightarrow 0$
induces by 3.2 an exact sequence
$0 \rightarrow pN \rightarrow pM \rightarrow p(M/N) \rightarrow 0.$
It follows $pM \neq 0$, because $p(M/N) \neq 0$. Therefore $p \in \operatorname{Cosupp}_R(M)$.
I don't understand why does there always exist a submodule $N$ of $M$ such that $M/N$ is an Artinian module?

What is [25, 2.16]? What is [25, 2.3]? What is 3.2? What is $\operatorname{Cos}_R(M)$? What is $\operatorname{Cosupp}_R(M)$?
